# updating the data in the database using asp.net (stored in a grid view)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ssms

I have a gridview containing employee details. i have an "edit" link button. Onclicking, it should update the record. But, in this code, instead of updating, it is creating a new record.

But, instead of update, a new record gets added.

```
protected void LinkButtonEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       using (GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((LinkButton)sender).Parent.Parent)
       {
           textBoxNameInput.Text = row.Cells[0].Text;
           HiddenEmployeeName.Value= row.Cells[0].Text;
           textBoxSalaryInput.Text = row.Cells[1].Text;
           HiddenSalary.Value = row.Cells[1].Text;
           textBoxDOJInput.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
           HiddenDOJ.Value = row.Cells[2].Text;
           var textToFind = row.Cells[3].Text;

           DropDownListDepartment.Items.FindByText(textToFind).Selected = true;
           DropDownListDepartment.ClearSelection();

           HiddenDepartmentName.Value = textToFind;
       }

       ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
   }

   protected void Update_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        var deptID = getDeptId(HiddenDepartmentName.Value);
        float Salary = float.Parse(HiddenSalary.Value);
        // string DateOfJoining = HiddenDOJ.Value;
        //  DateTime dateVal = Convert.ToDateTime(DateOfJoining,
        //System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("hi-IN").DateTimeFormat);
        int EmployeeID = getEmployeeID(HiddenEmployeeName.Value, Salary, deptID);

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            string EmployeeName = textBoxNameInput.Text;
            float SalaryUpadate = float.Parse(textBoxSalaryInput.Text);
            string DepartmentName = DropDownListDepartment.Text;
            int DepartmentID = getDeptId(DepartmentName);

            // DateTime DateOfJoining = Convert.ToDateTime(DOJ_Text.Text);
            // string DateOfJoiningUpdate = EditDOJ_Text.Text;
            //     DateTime dateValUpdate = Convert.ToDateTime(DateOfJoiningUpdate,
            //  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("hi-IN").DateTimeFormat);

            con.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET EmployeeName = @EmployeeName, SALARY = @Salary, DEPARTMENTID = @DepartmentID WHERE EMPLOYEEID = @EmployeeID";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeName", EmployeeName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DepartmentId", DepartmentID);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    public int getEmployeeID(string updateEmpolyeeName, float updateSalary, int deptID)
    {
        int EmpId = 0;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;

            con.Open();

            SqlDataReader rd;
            cmd.CommandText = "Select EmployeeId from Employee where EmployeeName='" + updateEmpolyeeName + "'and salary='" + updateSalary + "'and departmentId='" + deptID + "'";

            rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rd.Read())
            {
                EmpId = Int32.Parse(rd.GetValue(0).ToString());
            }
        }
        return EmpId;
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/editing-data-using-asp-net-gridview-control). It covers all the basics of GridView editing and updating.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: there should be a pop up page on clicking the edit/delete command @VDWWD

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed is that you don't have a parameter for @EmployeeID in here

```
    con.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET EmployeeName = @EmployeeName, SALARY = @Salary, DEPARTMENTID = @DepartmentID WHERE EMPLOYEEID = @EmployeeID";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeName", EmployeeName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DepartmentId", DepartmentID);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Another thing I will point out is that in your function getEmployeeID()...your getting an EmployeeID based on name,salery,department...There is no guarantee that those fields would be unique.
Put the actual EmployeeID into the grid and use it as the key.

As to why your inserting a record instead of updating?
I cant see any way possible that  Update_Btn_Click() would INSERT a record.
I would put a break point in there and make sure that is the code being executed.

You can hide the EmployeeID like this:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeID" HeaderText="EmployeeID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True">
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="hide" Width="0px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <ItemStyle CssClass="hide" Width="0px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</asp:BoundField>
```

Comment: i am not supposed to show the employeeId on the gridview. Is there a way out?